# Uploading large file in ASP.net IIS 7 or above

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to upload file having size more than 5MB, but i am etting error 
"maximum request length exceeded".

I already have the following code in web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Still I am having the error.

Comment: Try adding this `maxRequestLength` as well. I think you need both `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

In you web.config file, add this:-

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="3145728" /> <!--3145728KB=3072MB=3GB-->
</system.web>
```

and then

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```